# Rails: Remove CKEditor along with adding a new migration to drop it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, trumbowyg

i need to remove 'ckeditor gem' and replace it with 'trumbowyg_rails gem'
Ckeditor is properly implemented in all the pages also the migration is done for create_table "ckeditor_assets" how do i drop this migration and clean the rails app before adding trumbowyg_rails gem?

Comment: `rails d ckeditor:install` try this one

Comment: this destroys #########_create_ckeditor_assets in the db/migrate folder but in the schema.rb the  create_table "ckeditor_assets" still exists. Is there a way to create a new migration to destroy it so it will work in production?

Comment: just create migration for drop that `ckeditor table`

Answer (score 0):

To rollback the migration that was done previously you can use `rails db:rollback`. Remove gem using `gem uninstall ckeditor`

EDIT:

To delete using migration

```
rails g migration deleteTableTableName
```

Then open the file and

```
def up
    drop_table :table_name
end
```

and then

```
rails db:migrate
```

I have not done this(I prefer rollback) but this should work.

Comment: Is there a way to create a new migration to destroy it so it will work in production? i am not keen on using rake db:rollback